# Why MySQL does not return rows in same order as appeared in IN clause?

Tags: mysql

This query asks MySQL to return items from `product` table. I would like the results to be returned in order as appeared in `IN` clause.

```
select id, price 
from product 
where id IN (5552902, 5552737, 5552887, 5549436, 5552291, 5552897, 
             5550834, 5552794, 5548666, 5552621);

+---------+----------+
| id      | price    |
+---------+----------+
| 5548666 | 919.0000 |
| 5549436 | 939.0000 |
| 5550834 | 919.0000 |
| 5552291 | 939.0000 |
| 5552621 | 829.0000 |
| 5552737 | 999.0000 |
| 5552794 | 919.0000 |
| 5552887 | 999.0000 |
| 5552897 | 939.0000 |
| 5552902 | 999.0000 |
+---------+----------+
```

For some reason MySQL returns results without respecting the order and I have to use `ORDER BY price DESC` in order to get the desired results.

```
select id, price 
from product 
where id IN (5552902, 5552737, 5552887, 5549436, 5552291, 
             5552897, 5550834, 5552794, 5548666, 5552621) 
ORDER BY price DESC;

+---------+----------+
| id      | price    |
+---------+----------+
| 5552902 | 999.0000 |
| 5552887 | 999.0000 |
| 5552737 | 999.0000 |
| 5552291 | 939.0000 |
| 5549436 | 939.0000 |
| 5552897 | 939.0000 |
| 5550834 | 919.0000 |
| 5552794 | 919.0000 |
| 5548666 | 919.0000 |
| 5552621 | 829.0000 |
+---------+----------+
```

MySQL version is `5.6`. I am wondering why MySQL does not return items in "correct" order.

Comment: you always need to use an ORDER BY clause to order returned results, the way MySQL selects and retrieves results on a query , as far as I know, is different depending on the table type.

Comment: @Martin Is there any official docs regarding this issue?

Comment: Rows are usually ordered by the index column but this can vary although I don't know the details, I would suggest googling as I do not have authoritative links but if no index column is specified then how the results are ordered varys depending on the table type (as I've noticed with innoDb and MyISAM tables at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the order as in `in clause` , you may use `order by field` something as

```
select 
id, price from product 
where id IN (5552902, 5552737, 5552887, 5549436, 5552291, 5552897, 5550834, 5552794, 5548666, 5552621)
order by field(id,5552902, 5552737, 5552887, 5549436, 5552291, 5552897, 5550834, 5552794, 5548666, 5552621)
;
```

Comment: Thank you, this does what I needed. Could you please clarify why MySQL does not respect the IN clause?

Comment: Mysql does not guarantee returning data in order by and thats the reality. In some cases it does return the data in order with primary key ascending order but thats not  guaranteed. So you need to explicitly provide the order by clause or in your case field. There are other variant as well  i.e. doing order by with `case-when`